# Match string and move line to line before

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a large file with this info repeating in it. unfortunately it uses a fixed terminal that word wraps the file. I need to match anything on `172` and move it to the line above

```
wsmith 623456256 6-meg
   172.16.15.198 pppoe
```

output needs to be

```
wsmith 623456256 6-meg  172.16.15.198 pppoe
```

I cannot use awk and simple move the second line as there is other lines in the file that would be incorrectly formatted.

Comment: can you show sample input for those _another lines_ you are talking about? and expected output based on that. also show us your `awk` command you are trying and how it fails; please **[edit]** your question to add

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*172/ !{ N;s/\n[[:blank:]]*/ /; };' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need:

file:

```
wsmith 623456256 6-meg
 172.16.15.198 pppoe
wfwe fw efwe fw ef
fkp e
kswsmith 623456256 6-meg
  172.16.15.198 pppoe
wsmith 623456256 6-meg
  172.16.15.198 pppoe
ef
efwef w ef w efwef
wewsmith 623456256 6-meg
 172.16.15.198 pppoe
efwef
uiwsmith 623456256 6-meg
172.16.15.198 pppoe
```

```
awk 'BEGIN{set=0} NR>1 && /^ *172/{ print line,$0; set=1; next }
 NR>1 && !/^ *172/ && set==0{print line} {line=$0; set=0}' file
```

output:

```
wsmith 623456256 6-meg  172.16.15.198 pppoe
wfwe fw efwe fw ef
fkp e 
kswsmith 623456256 6-meg   172.16.15.198 pppoe
wsmith 623456256 6-meg   172.16.15.198 pppoe
ef
efwef w ef w efwef
wewsmith 623456256 6-meg  172.16.15.198 pppoe
efwef
uiwsmith 623456256 6-meg 172.16.15.198 pppoe
```

Comment: So odd situation, none of these would work just like what i had built on the file that is generated. but as soon as I edit the file that has the data in it and re-save the file using Vim or nano then run the command they all work. the file i am editing is a router backup through a bash script that pipes the output to a log file. the edit could be small by either just removing something or adding space.

Comment: Could be a line-ending problem that gets auto-corrected by the editor upon saving.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ed` editor, the command `g/172/-1,.j` would join any line containing the (sub)string `172` with the previous line.

Following this up with `,p` would print the whole buffer to standard output (and `Q` quits without saving):

```
$ cat file
wsmith 623456256 6-meg
   172.16.15.198 pppoe
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/172/-1,.j' ',p' 'Q' | ed -s file
wsmith 623456256 6-meg   172.16.15.198 pppoe
```

To make the matching a bit more specific, matching only lines starting with optional spaces and/or tabs and the string `172.`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^[[:blank:]]*172\./-1,.j' ',p' 'Q' | ed -s file
wsmith 623456256 6-meg   172.16.15.198 pppoe
```

To save to a new file, redirect the result.  To do an in-place edit, replace the `,p` and `Q` commands with the single `wq` command.